# Make geometry from GPUShader visible for F12 rendering

Tags: python, rendering, shaders, gpu, gpu-module

I'm using [GPUModule](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html) with shaders to render some points in the 3D view:

```
def render(self, context):
    shader = cache['shader']

    gpu.state.blend_set('ALPHA')

    vertices = ((-1, 0, -1), (1, 0, -1), (1, 0, -1), (-1, 0, -1))
    batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'POINTS', {'position': vertices})

    # uniforms
    proj_matrix = bpy.context.region_data.perspective_matrix
    object_matrix = bpy.data.objects['Empty'].matrix_world

    # pass uniforms to shader
    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float('projection_matrix', proj_matrix)
    shader.uniform_float('object_matrix', object_matrix)
    shader.uniform_float('alpha_radius', 1.0)
    batch.draw(shader)
```

By using Offscreen Rendering (described [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#copy-offscreen-rendering-result-back-to-ram)) I can render into the Offscreen Buffer and save it as a picture afterwards.

**Now my question is:** Is it possible to make the geometry drawn by the GPUShader also visible for the F12 rendering? Unfortunately the stuff from the shader is not shown in the F12 rendering.

I'd be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved this problem and wanted to share my perceptions if someone ever comes up to this question and needs help...

- I haven’t found a way to manipulate the image buffer the F12 renderer writes into.
- I also haven’t found a way to make the shader renderings visible to the F12 renderer though very intense research. Although I realized that the shader stuff is only visible in the viewport because I’m calling the following function. (It adds a draw handler that is called in every viewport frame, without that I wouldn’t see the shader stuff in the viewport either.)

> bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(handler, (self, context),
> ‘WINDOW’, ‘POST_VIEW’)

- This lead me to the idea to use bpy.app.handlers.render_pre. In theory I could have called this handler before rendering every frame. In this handler I tried to call my save_image function. For rendering animations this also didn’t work because of an No active GPU context found error that I couldn’t solve. Probably GPUModule doesn’t allow it to use the F12 renderer and shader rendering simultaneously.
- Though I found out while trying out the last bullet point that **it at least works for rendering images** by using compositing mode: In the image node I can open my previously via shader rendered picture and connect it to the output node. When pressing F12 exactly that input image is rendered. (Yes, I know that this is very ugly. But it works…)
  [image]

**How I finally “solved” my problem:**

- As I needed the shader stuff to be drawn into a video, I’m saving all the frames from the animation to disk and using Blender’s Video Editing mode to make a video out of all the frames. I never used this mode before and didn’t remember it exists. But that’s way easier than what I tried to do.

**TLDR**: I don’t think it’s possible to render via shader and F12 simultaneously because F12 uses GPU context settings that GPUModule doesn’t like or vice versa.